# how do you add picture from local folder instead of web link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is not my code i was searching about a problem and found this  but the person posted it 4 years ago i guess no hope.... how do you add picture from local folder in card?

```
              <div id="appB" class="containerB">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 order-first res-m-bttm-lg">
                        <card data-image="https://www.worldatlas.com/r/w728-h425-c728x425/upload/23/08/01/shutterstock-104644850.jpg">
                        <h1 slot="header">Spain</h1>
                        <p slot="content">Bet On Spain's Team playing against Portugal.</p>
                        <p slot="content">ETj9Qy3r5DyXw87qEHyp5gXhruFMuicEUR</p>
                        </card>
                    </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: From your local file system you mean? Why on Earth would you want arbitrary websites having access to your local file system in the first place?

Comment: That code depends on some outside code. For example the data-image attribute doesn't do anything normally in the browser. You need to write some other code that interacts with it. Same with the <card> element. Are you just using plain JavaScript?

Comment: yes there is js involved. i found this very cool parallax depth cards on codepen and i wanted to practice it in my local server but i can't find a way to add local picture in it. it only works with online links? i don't believe it lol there is a way but idk. i don't want to upload their code here cuz i dont know much about the code legalities but here is the link to their codepen https://codepen.io/andymerskin/pen/XNMWvQ

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it my previous answer was wrong. css url function can be to a local file. I'm not exactly sure what is wrong but try to go into dev tools and see what the background-image css property of the card-bg class element is.

Comment: src attribute docent work here i have already tried

Comment: @Faye are you doing this in the codepen?

Comment: no in my laptop localhost. found the code in codepen i was just practicing.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to save the image and put the path in the src attribute.

pretending you saved worldatlas.jpg at img folder, this is how itll be
`<img src="img/worldatlas.jpg">`

Answer (score 0):

Save the image you want to implement in your project folder and after that you can just use the src="*path*" attribute.